# Gtk3 TextView modifying font size and keeping the current visible text on screen

Tags: gtk3

I'm working with a Textview widget and I can modify the font-size of the Textview widget with the Ctrl key + mouse scroll wheel but my displayed text scrolls when I do it.... How do I keep the current text from scrolling up or down while I modify the font size of the Textview widget?

A few notable things about the code. The font-size is changed via styles and provider because I can't figure out how to get Pango to work with a TextView widget. I hardwired the code to retrieve some data from my $str = qx(perldoc -T -t -f split 2>&1)... You'll probably have to change this to your own data source.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use feature qw(state);

use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;

use CSS::Tiny;

use constant FONT_UNIT => 4;
use constant MAX_FONT_SIZE => 200;
use constant MIN_FONT_SIZE => 12;

use Glib qw(TRUE FALSE);
use Gtk3 qw(init);

sub killKey {
    my ($object, $event) = @_;
    my $c = lc chr ($event->keyval);
    Gtk3->main_quit if $c eq 'q';
    FALSE;
}

sub changeFontSize {
    my ($font_size, $amount) = @_;
    $font_size += $amount;
    $font_size .= "px";
    $font_size;
}

sub changeStyle {
    my ($css, $provider, $style) = @_;
    $style->remove_provider($provider);
    $provider->load_from_data($css->write_string);
    $style->add_provider(
        $provider, 
        Gtk3::STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION
    );
}

sub catchScroll {
    my ($object, $event, $data) = @_;
    my ($css, $provider, $style) = @{$data};
    my $dir = $event->direction;
    my ($ctrl, $mod) = @{$event->state};
    my $font_size = $css->{textview}->{q<font-size>};

    {
     no warnings qw<numeric>;
     $font_size += 0;
    }

    if ($ctrl eq q<control-mask> && $mod eq q<mod2-mask>) {
     if ($dir eq q<up>) {
        $css->{textview}->{q<font-size>} = 
            changeFontSize($font_size, FONT_UNIT)
                if $font_size < MAX_FONT_SIZE;
     }else{
        $css->{textview}->{q<font-size>} = 
            changeFontSize($font_size, -FONT_UNIT)
                if $font_size > MIN_FONT_SIZE;
     }
     changeStyle($css, $provider, $style);
    }

    FALSE;
}

my $window = Gtk3::Window->new(q<toplevel>);
my $scrWin = Gtk3::ScrolledWindow->new();
my $tView = Gtk3::TextView->new();
my $provider = Gtk3::CssProvider->new();

$provider->load_from_path("the.css");
my $style = $tView->get_style_context();
$style->add_provider($provider, Gtk3::STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);

my $css = CSS::Tiny->read_string($provider->to_string);

#hardwired data for the TextView
my $str = qx(perldoc -T -t -f split 2>&1);

my $buf = $tView->get_buffer();
$buf->set_text($str);
my $sIter = $buf->get_start_iter();
$buf->place_cursor($sIter);
$tView->set_editable(FALSE);

$window->add_events(q<GDK_KEY_PRESS_MASK>);
$window->add_events(q<GDK_SCROLL_MASK>);

$window->signal_connect(delete_event => sub{Gtk3->main_quit; FALSE});
$window->signal_connect(key_press_event => \&killKey);
$window->signal_connect(
    scroll_event =>
    \&catchScroll,
    [$css, $provider, $style]
);

$window->set_decorated(FALSE);
$window->set_position(q<center>);
$window->fullscreen;

$scrWin->add($tView);
$window->add($scrWin);
$window->show_all;

Gtk3::main;
```

the.css

```
text {
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    color: rgb(0,255,0);
}

textview {
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Do you return `GDK_EVENT_STOP` from you scroll handler?

Comment: I'm not using GDK_EVENT_STOP because I'm writing this in Perl and they use FALSE and TRUE to stop the propagation of an event handler. I just want to know if this possible with C and Gtk3 and then I'll see if the functionality is available with Perl's Gtk3.

Comment: Then do you stop event propagation? Please include code to make the question better

Comment: I updated the original post to include the code.

Comment: What is that `FALSE` at the end of `catchScroll`? Is it return value? `GDK_EVENT_STOP` is defined as `TRUE`, if you return `FALSE` you don't prevent default handler from executing.

Comment: It doesn't matter what it returns(FALSE or TRUE). Change the font size and text starts scrolling.